# Why Deeplinking in ionic apps didn't working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm setting some deeplinking on my apps to open some URL. I've try this code but it seems don't work.

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=solusipay --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=blablabla.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/
```

I have try this : https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/

Is there something I missed in there?

Answer (score 1):

I am Using [Firebase Dynamic links](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/) Ionic native plugin it is in beta stage but working fine for deeplinking.

config.xml:

```
 <platform name="ios">
   <preference name="GoogleIOSClientId" value="..." />
</platform>
<platform name="android">
   <preference name="GoogleAndroidClientId" value="..." />
</platform>
```

Install :

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks --save --variable APP_DOMAIN="example.com" --variable APP_PATH="/"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links
```

Usage:

```
import { FirebaseDynamicLinks } from '@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links';


constructor(private firebaseDynamicLinks: FirebaseDynamicLinks) { }

...
// Handle the logic here after opening the app with the Dynamic link
this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink()
  .subscribe((res: any) => console.log(res), (error:any) => console.log(error));
```

Hope you find solution !! Happy Coding !!!